# qt ftp->list() - how to read how many bytes read

Tags: qt, list, ftp

when i do ftp->list() i'm expecting to get the bytes read and show it.
problem is i dont see any option for this (only to ftp->get() using dataTransferProgress).

i want to able also to print at the end of the ftp->list() process msg like this:
List Complete: 24,477 bytes in 0.52 seconds (47.53KB/s)

Comment: Should we guess what ftp variable is?

Comment: sorry ? can u please tell what more details u need ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using [QFtp](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qftp.html). As you mentioned dataTransferProgress signal is not emitted for LIST command. I guess what you could try to do is: get the number of bytes available in the data socket usig [ftp()->bytesAvailable](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qftp.html#bytesAvailable) in your [listInfo](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qftp.html#listInfo) signal slot. It should reduce every time a new line (and it should be one line for a folder) is read from the socket. This would give you the number of bytes used by a single folder. Multiply it by the number of folders received and it should get you the (aproximate) number for bytes transfered.

Comment: although it displays the current bytes read i would also like to know how to display the traditional ftp line: List Complete: 24,477 bytes in 0.52 seconds (47.53KB/s) without doing calculations...